# Which builder approach is preferable?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

I'm reading "Effective Java 2n Edition" from Joshua Bloch. My question is about Item 2 "Consider a builder when faced with many constructor parameters".

Shortened example from the book:

```
public class NutritionFacts {
    private final int calories;

    public static class Builder {
        private int calories = 0;

        public Builder(){}

        public Builder calories(int val) {
            calories = val;
            return this;
        }

        public NutritionFacts build(){
           return new NutritionFacts(this);
        }
    }

    private NutritionFacts(Builder builder){
        calories = builder.calories;
    }
}
```

invoke it: `NutritionFacs cocaCola = new NutritionFacts.Builder().calories(300).build()`

My version

```
public class NutritionFacts {
    private int calories;

    public NutritionFacts calories(int calories) {
        this.calories = calories;
        return this;
    }
}
```

invoke: `NutritionFacts cocaCola = new NutritionFacts().calories(300);`

So what's the advantage of the example from the book? I only see the immutability which is not possible with my solution.

Comment: Yes, immutability is it. Your implementation isn't actually a builder at all - it's just a mutable type. If you want a mutable type, you don't need a builder. Personally, I like immutability in many contexts.

Comment: First you are invoking first builder wrong, you are creating two instances of NutritionFacts. You should do `NutritionFacts.Builder().calories(300).build()` or `Builder().calories(300).build()` and second thing as @JonSkeet said, your implementation is not a builder

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Eclipse? In that case I recomend you to install the addon/plugin [Fluent Builder](https://code.google.com/p/fluent-builders-generator-eclipse-plugin/). I use it quite often to generate builders of entities for testing purposes.

This plugin generates a very good example of how a builder is constructed. I have to admit that it isn't a pure Builder Pattern but a Fluent Pattern. Anyway, I believe its code is pretty good for you to learn the purpose of Builder Pattern and its benefits.

Comment: No, I'm using IntelliJ. The question is not about generating or what is the purpose of a builder.